# Undefined mixin 'box-shadow' with Active Admin Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have a Rails 3.2 app using ActiveAdmin 1.0 and I'm using the [active_admin_editor gem here](https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor).

Anytime I try to load the I get the error below.  The front end loads fine and also if I remove the active_admin_editor gem, ActiveAdmin loads fine.

I've searched all over google & SO for a few days trying to figure out the answer.

Undefined mixin 'box-shadow' in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/active_admin_editor-1.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/editor.css.scss

Application.css.scss

```
*= require_self
*= require formtastic-bootstrap
*= require my_styles
*= require active_admin/editor/wysiwyg
```

My application layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Latest minified Font Awesome CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/assets/my_styles-6077c0d3b7523ad80195404b9270b1ac.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="/assets/application-0c2344779e38105475d0e1be9a815723.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: box-shadow is a bootstrap mixin, are you _sure_ you have bootstrap required before AA and that mixing are being called correctly?

Comment: @Isotope I think that may be the problem.  I'm using the Bootstrap CDN for the css and the javascript, but I'm trying to figure out how to import it so that AA gets it since AA has it's own layout.

Comment: create two different layouts, one for your application and the other for the AA backend

Comment: I had to use an old version of bourbon to make this working. gem 'bourbon', '3.2.4'

Answer (score 8):

Try to use active_admin_editor on github.

```
gem 'active_admin_editor', github: 'ejholmes/active_admin_editor'
```

Answer (score 4):

For *github: 'ejholmes/active_admin_editor'* this repo gemspec is invaild.

Try with following following repo:

```
gem 'active_admin_editor', github: 'boontdustie/active_admin_editor'
```

This resolves your problem.

Comment: legend! worked, but would be great if the official gem would be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the mixing 'box-shadow' which was considered deprecated, I could solve it with a minimal change, this version is available on a personal fork of this gem, i'm waiting for the pull request.

https://github.com/JLNeoh/active_admin_editor

Answer (score 0):

I used this gem: [activeadmin-wysihtml5](https://github.com/unmantained-activeadmin-plugins/activeadmin-wysihtml5) Even though it is unmaintained, it had Hardcoded box-shadow.

Comment: Please dont't create a new answer for comments like that. Create a new comment instead. Thank you.